# Best approach to building XML with some default values

Tags: c#, xml, oop

I need to create a large XML document. The problem is that there are alot of default values that will never change. Which approach is best to generate the following piece of XML.

```
<Membership>
   <Clients>
      <Client>
        <FirstName>Bilbo</FirstName>
        <LastName>Baggins</LastName>
      </Client>
  </Client>
</Membership>
```

I have to build an XML. What is the best approach considering the following:

**Approach 1 (My Current Approach)**

Create an instance of the following classes, inject the data from the form, and serialise it into XML.

```
public class Membership
{
    public List<Account> Accounts {get;set;}
    //Other Properties
} 

public class Account
{
    List<Client> Clients { get; set; }   
}

public class Client
{
   public ClientDetails Details { get; set; }
   public Boolean WebAccess     { get; set; }
}

public class ClientDetails
{
   public string FirstName      { get; set; }
   public string LastName       { get; set; }
}
```

The value of some properties rely on other properties e.g Gender on Title (If identify as Mr then set gender as male). From my understanding I can't use auto-implementing properties as specified above to do this. I wan't to avoid this approach as this would involve a large constructor.

**Approach 2**

Buid the entire XML documents using creating instances of various XML documents. For example one file (Membership.xml) would define the overall structure of the XML document and another file would define the structure of only a client.

If I wanted to create a list of clients I would create several instances of the client.xml file and append it to the Clients node of the Membership.xml intsance.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Seems opinion based.  Both approaches will work of course.

Comment: Are you going to use the XML file as an application database? When you say best approach in which requisite, I mean - have a code that humans can easily understand? XML processing performance? data structure? What you're looking for?

Comment: @Thiago Avelino This XML would be sent to an API as an HTTP request. I am trying to find the best approach to set the default values that the API is expecting e.g accountType codes etc that will never change

Comment: Assuming you control other end too - use JSON could be better approach for web request :) (especially if you ever try to use it from browser too).

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov Its not my API so unfortunately I have very limited control over it. For this specific request it only accepts XML :(

Comment: If it were me, I would use SQL Lite so I have an actual database to store my records, and then to get the XML version I would serialize the database to an XML file, basically a dump.

That way you can make use of EntityFramework, or a Micro ORM, or just straight ADO.Net to query information from the file instead of having to load the whole thing into ram to work with it.

Comment: If there are a lot of default values that never change, you can manually create said XML file, then use the XML transformation engine to add your changes to it... But even then the whole thing will be loaded, manipulated, and resaved everytime..

The problem with XML is you can't to append inserts etc, it always involves a full load and full save everytime (afaik, custom engines unknown etc).

That's why I would take the Database Approach.

Comment: @Ryios setting up my own database is not an option, although I do agree it would be easier, as my client wants me to use this API. The api handles the database interactions. I simply have to send the API the data entered by the user in the application form.

Comment: Ah, a webservice response.  What kind of web service is it?  Rest, WCF, Soap?

If it's WCF or Soap, you can add a service referrence to it in your VS project and it will generate all the Classes for you, then you can just populate them with data and send them.

If it's rest it should accept XML or JSON, unless they wrote their service layer from scratch and only accept xml.

If it does accept JSON it would be easier to use NewtonSoft.JSON (nuget package) to serialize your classes to json as JSON isn't going to complicate things by adding namespaces etc.

Comment: For example, if there web service is written as Rest with Microsoft WebApi, it should accept JSON or XML based on the Mime type of the posted document.  When posting JSON the mime type will be application/json and the webservice should accept it just as it would xml.  Json is a lot easier to work with in c# because you can create anonymous types all day long and just serialize them in 1 line of code.

Comment: @Rios I beleive it is REST. Unfortunately I can only send XML. If I was to generate my XML from existing XML files e.g Client.xml, Membership.xml, Account.xml each time the user posted the form what would be the performance implications over uses purely classes?

Answer (score 1):

**If possible use a Database for that.**

**If you don't have the database option**, I'd recommend you to have the multiple XML files approach(2nd option), since you may have multiple concurrent HTTP requests the processing would be more efficient with multiple files, better than 1 xml file shared by all the users.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will work for you:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> clientNames = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        // substitute with values from a file or database
        clientNames.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Bilbo", "Baggins"));
        clientNames.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Frodo", "Baggins"));
        var xml = BuildXml(clientNames);
        Console.WriteLine(xml);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static XElement BuildXml(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> clientNames)
    {
        XElement membership = new XElement("Membership");
        XElement clients = new XElement("Clients");
        membership.Add(clients);
        foreach (var kvp in clientNames)
        {
            XElement client = new XElement("Client");
            client.Add(new XElement("FirstName", kvp.Key), new XElement("LastName", kvp.Value));
            clients.Add(client);
        }
        return membership;
    }
```

Comment: Hi there thanks for the reply. This was sort of what I was thinking but woudn't it be easier to suck in XML from an XML file with the default values already set. I sort of have the same problem at the moment where default values have to be set everytime you create an instance of the class. Thanks for telling me how to create XML nodes on the fly. I did not know this.